# Laravel 5 Model namespace class not found

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-5

I am trying to store my models in a custom namespace and directory structure as shown here:

[image]

I have:

```
namespace Modules\Core;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        $user = new User;
        return view('core::test');
    }

}
```

But I am getting:

```
FatalErrorException in TestController.php line 8:
Class 'Modules\Core\User' not found
```

Which is wrong anyway, so I thought it must be 'Modules\Core\Models\User'. I tried this and I still got the same error (just with a different class name).

My model:

```
namespace Modules\Core;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class User Extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'users';
}
```

How can I get access to this model in the TestController?

---

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Modules\Core\Controllers'), function() {
    Route::get('/test', ['uses' => 'TestController@index']);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your controller is stored in Modules/Core/Controllers, the namespace should be `namespace Modules\Core\Controllers;`

And likewise, if the model is stored in Modules/Core/Models, its namespace is `namespace Modules\Core\Models;`

Then, in the controller, import it before using it:

```
<?php namespace Modules\Core\Controllers;

use Modules\Core\Models\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {

    public function index(){
        $user = new User;
        return view('core::test');
    }

}
```

Comment: How should I adjust my router (see edit)? It's giving me an error at the moment that the class can't be found.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as above. In my case I had the following namespace:

```
namespace Modules\XMLApi;
```

I got the same error as above. When I changed the namespace to the following:

```
namespace Modules\XmlApi;
```

Then run the following command:
composer dump-autoload

Then it worked.

Comment: Thanks. The command made me realize I had an extra `,` in the `composer.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

You should edit your `routes.php` file:

```
Route::group(array('namespace' => 'Modules\Core\Controllers'), function() {
    Route::get('/test', ['uses' => '\Modules\Core\TestController@index']);
});
```

to use full together with namespace

Comment: That gives me: Class Modules\Core\Controllers\\Modules\Core\TestController does not exist

Comment: Weird, I did composer dump and it now works. I didn't think you have to do that if you changed a path in a file? :S

Comment: @imperium2335 using 'composer dump' just fixed a similar problem for me too! Thanks for your comment.